# If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$m then what's the intuitive reason behind $Z :=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Tags: statistics

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$m then what's the intuitive reason behind $Z :=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$? I know how it is so using calculations, but I would like to see the intuitive explanation for a better understanding.

$\mathcal{N}$ stands for the normal distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you go from $X$ to $X-\mu$ you are shifting so you get to $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Then when you divide by a constant, you are keeping the middle at 0 but you are scaling the width. So that $\sigma^2$ changes to $1$.

It may be easier to instead of using a normal distribution to use a uniform distribution on an interval centered at $\mu$ and with width $\sigma$ in either direction. That is to say it is supported between $\mu \pm \sigma$. When you do the shift and divide on this, you can picture the rectangle moving to be centered on $0$ and then squishing (while preserving total area=1) so that it's endpoints are at $\pm 1$ instead.

Comment: Ah, the interval is $\mu \pm \sigma$. Now I see why we divide by $\sigma$ and not $\sigma^2$. Thanks @AHusain

Answer (score 1):

1. for any r.v. $X$, if $E(X)=\mu$ and $V(X)=\sigma^2$ (and they are finite), if you define $$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$ it is true that $$E(Z)=E\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=\frac{E(X)-\mu}{\sigma}=0\ \ \ \text{and}$$ $$V(Z)=V\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=\frac{V(X)}{\sigma^2}=1$$ by the properties of the expected value and the variance. Normality is not needed for this result.
2. If you have a r.v. $X$ that is Normal, $Z=a X+b$ is also Normal by the properties of the Normal distribution for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. If you set $a=1/\sigma$ and $b=-\mu/\sigma$ and use the result in 1. you conclude that $Z$ is Normal$(0,1)$.